# relationship attributes in onetomany

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

lets say I want to model the following:

There Are *Texts*, that can have **many** *Quotes*, each *Quote* is Part of **one** *Text*. On top of that, each Quote is on a specific *Page* of one Text.

I found that there is an [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) relationship Model for ManyToMany fields, that would allow me to add Attributes to the relation (like the Option to define a Page). Is that also possible on the OneToMany-Relationship? How can I model that in django?

That is what I have so far

```
class Text(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Quote(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    page = models.IntegerField()

class Text(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quote = models.ManyToMany(Quote, blank=True, null=True)
```

Sample usage:

```
t = Text.objects.create('My Text')
q = Quote.objects.create('Quote 1', 2)
q2 = Quote.objects.create('Quote 2', 2)
t.quote_set.add(q)
t.quote_set.add(q2)
t.save()
```

Comment: I chose @Germanos answer as accepted, as for me, the Page is in a logical way no attribute of the Quote. Thank you.

Comment: Finally I ended up doing this, i.e. added a page Attribute to the Quote Model. The problem with the other one was an impossibility to edit the Models in django-admin. As I advance and find further problems/caveats, ill let us know

Comment: Glad that you solved your issue. This way, though, you may end up with a quote belonging to a page that does not exist in a text. At least, it's not a constraint enforced by the relation. As for the admin, you might want to have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `Page` object with a ForeignKey to `Text`, and then the `source` ForeignKey of `Quote` should target a `Page` object.

Something like:

```
class Text(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Page(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.ForeignKey(Text)

class Quote(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
```

You can find out the `Text` instance for a given `Quote` traversing the page relation:

```
quote.page.text
```